# How do I open project in Android Studio, getting errors

Tags: android, project

Here are the steps and files I choose to open the project. They show different errors.
What can I do, I just want to export my app as signed apk.
Steps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

App must be complied successfully to get an apk. Please share your gradle files to get your error fixed. Only thing I can assume from your screenshot you didn't correctly added dependency modules.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this language. Should specify that someone else(Freelancer) made the app and sent me the files